# Array values replaced rather than pushed

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build a multidimensional array like `array(years => array(months))`. Each new month added to a year replaces the old month value in the year array rather than appending the value.

```
<?php 
$dates = array();
foreach (Blog::all() as $blog) {
    $date_year = date("Y", strtotime($blog->created_at));
    $date_month = date("F", strtotime($blog->created_at));
    if (!in_array($date_year, $dates)) {
        $dates[$date_year] = array();
    }
    if (!in_array($date_month, $dates[$date_year])) {
        $dates[$date_year][] = $date_month;
        print $date_year." ".$date_month."<br>";
    }
}
print_r($dates); ?>
```

Outputs:

`Array ( [2009] => Array ( [0] => December ) [2010] => Array ( [0] => March ) [2011] => Array ( [0] => August ) [2012] => Array ( [0] => November ) [2013] => Array ( [0] => October ) [2014] => Array ( [0] => April ) )`

The months displayed are the last month available for each year. I have also tried with `array_push($dates[$date_year], $date_month)` for the same result.

Comment: Isn't it `$dates["$date_year"][] = "$date_month";` -> `$dates["$date_year"] = array($date_month);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The year array is being overwritten each time here:

```
if (!in_array($date_year, $dates)) {
    $dates[$date_year] = array();
}
```

Check the array keys instead of the array values with `array_key_exists`:

```
if (!array_key_exists($date_year, $dates)) {
    $dates[$date_year] = array();
}
```

Or, better yet IMO, use `isset` as suggested by vp_arth below.  (For succintness.)

```
if (!isset($dates[$date_year])) {
    $dates[$date_year] = array();
}
```

Comment: is there any difference with `isset`?

Comment: @vp_arth Yeah I'm pretty sure `isset` would work fine as well:  `if (!isset($dates[$date_year]))`